# $f:\mathbb Q\to\mathbb C$ satisfying $f(x_1+\dots+x_{1988})=f(x_1)\dots f(x_{1988})$ and $\overline{f(1988)}f(x)=f(1988)\overline{f(x)}$

Tags: functions, complex-numbers, contest-math, functional-equations

I came across this super interesting question (Chinese Team Selection Test 1988, Problem 2) which I have not quite seen something like this and not quite sure where to start. Any suggestions/ help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

> Find all functions $f: \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{C}$ satisfying
>
> 1. For any $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{1988} \in \mathbb{Q}$, $f(x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_{1988}) = f(x_1)f(x_2) \dots f(x_{1988})$.
> 2. $\overline{f(1988)}f(x) = f(1988)\overline{f(x)}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Well, one trivial solution is $f(x) =0$.

Comment: You can start by just substituting values. Can you find the value of $f(0)$ when $f(x)$ is not the zero function? You can also write $f(x+y)c=f(x)f(y)$ for some suitable $c$.

Comment: @Aravind I got $(f(0))^{1987} =1$ but was unable to find the suitable $c$ you speak of. Could you provide a few hints? P. S. My work was that I put $f(x) = a(x)  + i b(x)$,  where $a$ and $b$ always return  real values, and applying the conditions one solution I got was $f(x) = \alpha ^ x$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write $n$ for $1988$.

One obvious solution is $f = 0$, the constant zero function. We exclude this case in the following.

Setting $x_2 = \cdots = x_n = 0$, we get $f(x_1) = f(x_1)f(0)^{n - 1}$. Choosing $x_1$ such that $f(x_1) \neq 0$, we get $f(0)^{n - 1} = 1$.

We write $a = f(0)$. It is an $(n - 1)$-st root of unity, hence nonzero.

Setting $x_3 = \cdots = x_n = 0$, we get $f(x_1 + x_2) = f(x_1)f(x_2)a^{n - 2} = f(x_1)f(x_2)a^{-1}$. In particular, setting $x_2 = -x_1$ shows that $f(x) \neq 0$ for any $x\in \Bbb Q$.

We define $g(x) = a^{-1}f(x)$. The above identity then translates to $g(x_1 + x_2) = g(x_1)g(x_2)$. Taking absolute values gives $|g(x_1 + x_2)| = |g(x_1)|\cdot|g(x_2)|$.

We write $b = |g(1)|$, a positive real number. It follows that $|g(k)| = b^k$ for any integer $k$, and then $|g(x)| = b^x$ for any rational number $x$.

From the identity $\overline{f(n)}f(x) = f(n)\overline{f(x)}$, we get $\overline{g(n)}g(x) = g(n)\overline{g(x)}$. Multiplying both sides by $g(n)g(x)$ gives $|g(n)|^2 g(x)^2 = g(n)^2|g(x)|^2$, or $b^{2n}g(2x) = b^{2x}g(2n)$.

We rewrite the last identity as $g(2x - 2n) = b^{2x - 2n}$. This being true for all $x \in \Bbb Q$, we have $g(x) = b^x$ for all $x\in \Bbb Q$.

Thus $f(x) = a\cdot b^x$, where $a$ is an $(n - 1)$-st root of unity and $b$ is a positive real number.

Conversely, it is easy to check that any function $f$ of this form satisfies the two conditions in the question. Therefore (together with the zero function) we have found all of them.

Comment: +1. Nice solution. But there's a typo, when you get $f(x_1 +x_2)=a^{-1}f(x_1)f(x_2)$ you have put $x_i=0$ from $i=2$ instead of $i=3$.

Comment: @AryanSonwatikar Thank you, I also found this typo. Corrected now.